# How to add a condition to a double summation

Tags: summation

I want to write the following equation in Mathematica, but I don't know how to do that

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways is as follows.

```
\[Lambda][1]* Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*Sum[\[Lambda][1]^i*\[Lambda][2]^j*
 KroneckerDelta[i + j - n + 1], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, 0, n - 1}]*
 t^n/n!, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> $-\frac{\lambda (1) e^{\lambda (1) (-t)-\lambda (2) t} \left(e^{\lambda (2) t}-e^{\lambda (1) t}\right)}{\lambda (1)-\lambda (2)}$

Comment: Another way is `\[Lambda][1]*
 Sum[(-1)^(n - 1)*
   Sum[\[Lambda][1]^i*\[Lambda][2]^(n - 1 - i), {i, 0, n - 1}]*
   t^n/n!, {n, 1, Infinity}]`.